# node project does not package (and run) correctly on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node project that compiles and runs perfectly fine on my local mac box. However, when i git clone, npm install and run it on a remote (ubuntu) box it almost seems like the packaging is not working correctly.

Here is the stack trace

```
Error: Cannot find module './MyModule'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myproject/be/util/index.js:7:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at loader (/myproject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/myproject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myproject/be/fetch.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at loader (/myproject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
```

The node and npm versions are the same. Any pointers on where i could look?

Comment: It's complaining that it either cannot find the file `MyModule.js` or `MyModule/index.js`. Do you have the file in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it was this syntax inside my 'util/index.js' that was throwing errors on ubuntu (but worked fine on my mac)

```
export * from './FileA'
export * from './FileB'
export * from './FileC'
```

I just pasted all the contents of file's A,B and C inside 'util/index.js' and it started working.